# Send redis message with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, redis

I'm trying to find a way to send a redis message to a specific channel from a website. I think [this](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis) might work, but I don't know how to use it and there is very little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is supposed to only connect with a server, not directly with a client such as a browser (it's actually impossible to *directly* connect to redis from a browser).

You can achieve that running webdis on the server with redis and connecting to it from the browser, resulting in an infrastructure similar to this:

```
Client       Server
----------------------
         |
         |
Browser ---> webdis
         |     |
         |     |
         |     v
         |   redis
```

Note that it would not be secure, because the client on the browser **could** do whatever he wants with your redis database.

Usually, a custom server program is implemented that forward your commands to the redis server in a controlled way:

```
Client       Server
----------------------
         |
         |
Browser ---> custom server
         |        |
         |        |
         |        v
         |      redis
```

Comment: How would I create a custom server program to forward the redis messages?

Comment: What @gbalduzzi was referring to was to use [Webdis](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis), which is an HTTP server that you can send requests to (as in HTTP requests), and it will convert those into Redis commands, query Redis, and send you back the response in JSON or other formats. For example if you fetch `/GET/foo` it will return the value of the key `foo` from Redis.
Webdis *is* this "custom server program to forward the redis messages". That's all it does.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Webdis.